# Do we need type annotations even after adding type assertions in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

Do we really need to specify the type of a variable if we specify `as` in Typescript?

For example: The below code gives me same type of Object. But, I wanna know the correct way to do this.

```js
const x: Student = {
  name: "John"
}

// is the above same as below

const x = {
  name: "John"
} as Student;

// or do we need to specify both

const x: Student = {
  name: "John"
} as Student;

export interface Student {
  name: string,
  id?: string
}
```

Comment: ① What you're calling a "type declaration" is conventionally called a [*type annotation*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables).  And what you're calling "specify `as`" is conventionally called a [*type assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  Please consider [edit]ing to use the conventional terminology so that it's easier for you and others to search for relevant information.

Comment: ② You don't need to both annotate and assert; annotations are generally preferred to assertions; assertions are checked more loosely than annotations, to allow you to avoid compiler errors. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Got it. Edited the question. So, for strict check Type Annotations. Thanks

Comment: @tangel You might looking for the [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator instead of an assertion. The behavior is more similar to an annotation in regard to validation (each serves a different purpose)… but as has already been mentioned: annotations are more common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) and [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) serve different but partially overlapping needs; it's rare indeed that you'd ever want to use both.

---

A *type annotation* lets you explicitly choose the type of a variable.  It is quite often unnecessary; without an explicit type annotation the variable's type can often be [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) by the type of its initializing value.  If that value's type suffices for your needs, then an annotation is essentially redundant.  If that value's type is insufficient, then an annotation is helpful.  For example in

```
const x = { name: "John" }
/* const x: { name: string; } */
```

the compiler infers the type of `x` as `{name: string}`.  This is assignable to `Student`, and so depending on your use case it might suffice:

```
function acceptStudent(s: Student) { }
acceptStudent(x); // works
```

But you should feel free to use an annotation if you prefer:

```
const x: Student = {
  name: "John"
}
```

Type annotations are checked fairly strictly.  If you annotate a variable with a type incompatible with its initializer, you'll get an error:

```
const x: Student = { // error!
  id: "John",
}
```

---

A *type assertion* on the other hand lets you claim that an expression is of a certain type. This is used primarily when you know more about the type of an expression than the compiler can verify... you *assert* it, despite the compiler's inability to see that the assertion is true.  Actually another use case is when you need to deliberately *lie* to the compiler about the type of an expression in order to proceed. Again it is also quite often unnecessary, since the compiler's inferred types for such expressions is usually reasonable.  But there are times where you want to change the compiler's view about an expression's type:

```
const x = {
  id: "John"
} as Student; // no error
```

Here the compiler does not complain, even though `{id: "John"}` is not a valid `Student`.  It's close enough, though, for the compiler to accept your assertion.

---

So it depends on what your needs are. The general advice here is roughly: prefer annotations over assertions, and prefer inference over annotations.  If inference suffices, then use it.  If not, then annotate.  If that still doesn't work, then consider asserting (but be careful).  And using *both* is almost certainly overkill.  Once you assert the type of an initializing expression, that type will be the inferred type for the variable, and an annotation is therefore redundant.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YyDeAoLSnwHtgoAXJAdyQF4kMlRIAuJAIgCkCALYFpAX1xIA9ACp8RUhWZ0GEZqQBOAS2ABzANz8kIoTjwAzAK7B4JJUSQJEMEgGUShgCYRgJABRRm9py5IBKWn5BKwgbb2dXN3I-TSEhCgIFAGsoPXFiMgAPLwcIshpsPDxZZnYuHkEBQUIMpABPalpBYvA5Vg5uFkrLKCRw33U0mskALxyfV0bCopL28q68Ph6+3IG0iEyYRLIVEggFfQRkfsnplqYkRRVVABpmpCVHAH55EmU1Sqwq2VgjpAAVcgEJp4YZZcZ5KbCeL7BSJACE90epQ6PDui2qEjIDQKSMcKPm3RAvROJEGmNqYxWE3yIKKyLmnSJJNWrnJeA2WwUO1c+0OiGpkLO9Far3etzxL0ub2unyqQA)

Comment: Type Annotations are also helpful to ensure the inference of a value is of the expected type. This allows for catching errors when initializing critical values.

I would only recommend assertions if you are doing things where the compiler has no way to infer the type ,like parsing a JSON string  into a JSON object or are using Generics for a complex type where you've implemented all the logic required to ensure the resulting values are of the type you are asserting.