# Typescript nested property in interface isn't required?

Tags: typescript

I've got an interface with a nested object:

```
export interface Person {
    PersonWrapper: {
        name: string;
        address: string
        email?: string;
    }
}
```

If I try and create an object from it, it seems that *name* is not required, but it should be. It's not defined as an optional property in the interface. Here's how I create it:

```
const payload = {
    PersonObj: {
        address: '123 memory lane'
    }
} as Person;
```

Why aren't I getting a compile-time error saying that *name* is required? If I forget to wrap it in *PersonWrapper* then I definitely get an error.

Comment: If you are going to use `PersonObj` you will definitely get the error. It should be `PersonWrapper`, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are not using [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) but using [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), for the compiler, you are close enough to the `Person`, thus it doesn't complain about the missing properties. To fix it, use type annotation instead:

```
// expected error
const payload: Person = {
  PersonWrapper: {
    address: "123 memory lane",
  },
};
```

You can read more about the difference between type annotation and assertion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76386048/do-we-need-type-annotations-even-after-adding-type-assertions-in-typescript/76386242#76386242)

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript distinguish:

1. Type Annotation

   ```
   let name: string;
   ```
2. Type Assertion

   ```
   let name = getSomeValue() as string;
   ```

As per TypeScript document, type assertion is loose, compared to type annotation (which is stricter):

> TypeScript only allows type assertions which convert to a more specific or less specific version of a type. This rule prevents “impossible” coercions [...]
>
> SOURCE: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions